# Fastest way to search in sorted static array

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, optimization

I am looking for the fastest way to search in a sorted, fixed array of 32 bit keys. The array size and data is static and will never change. The size of this array is ~1000-10000 unique elements. The search range is significantly broader (~100000) so a lot of searched values will not be found. I am interested in exact matches only.

Here is how the search proceeds:

1. Generate ~100 keys. These keys are in order of relevance so they can't be simply sorted
2. Search for the set of ~100 keys in a collection of static arrays (typically between 50 and 300 of them)
3. Stop the search when we have found enough matching results (hence the importance of not sorting the keys to get the most relevant results)

A potentially interesting property of the keys is that even if they are not close in term of integer value, most of them will only have a few different bits (~1-4) from their closest neighbor.

Most answers I found point towards binary search but none deal with the case of a static array, which probably opens up some optimization possibilities.

I have full control over the data structure, right now it is a fixed, sorted array but I could change that if it's not optimal. I could also add precomputed information since the data doesn't change if it doesn't take an unreasonable amount of memory.

The goal is to be efficient both in CPU and memory although CPU is the priority here.

Using C++ although that probably won't affect the answer much.

Comment: If you have control over the data structure, why is the search space divided into "50-300" different arrays, instead of being in a single sorted array?

Comment: Binary search is probably still fastest, especially if the static data is already sorted (and wouldn't require any manipulating of the data).  Unless you wanted to load the data into a bunch of hashed containers (if you're looking for only exact matches) if you have the right hashing algorithm that may perform better.

Comment: @TylerDurden 2 reasons. 1. We don't search in every array, there are about 2000 of them and the one that get searched depend on the current request. 2. Each array is a set of key bound to a specific piece of data, different set have keys that will have the same numeric value but not the same meaning.

Comment: A static array to search usually makes (perfect) hashing a good idea. What do you mean by enough matching results?

Comment: @JonChesterfield Within a given search, if we have found a predetermined number of matches, we stop the search and work with these results. I will look into perfect hashing

Comment: @user2413068, how much extra memory do you have per array, and how much extra time do you have for pre-processing? (e.g. x10 memory, x50 pre-process). Is relatively long pre-processing, and significant memory overhead acceptable? Can pre-processing be performed once during the service start?

Comment: Possibly a Trie, with 5 or 6 bit keys at each level, 5 or 4 levels, and the last level just being a list of bits (128 or 256) for which IDs are in the arrays you're searching.  Not sure how much space this would require, or if this would be faster than a straight binary search (due to memory caching and locality).

Comment: @user3707125. Preprocessing is done offline so I have theoritically infinite Preprocessing time. Memory would be in the order of about 1k per array.

Comment: An array of 10,000 32-bit keys is 40,000 bytes. The whole 100,000 range presented as bits (key is present/absent) is only 12,500 bytes. Why not store the arrays like that? The lookup time would be nearly instant.

Comment: @m69 the key is a pair and I need the other value, also the search space is unknown at pre process time and not constant at runtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering that your static arrays never change, and that you have infinite pre-processing power I think the best approach would be to create a specific hash function for each of your arrays.

My approach - define a parameterized hash function (code in java):

```
private static Function<Long, Integer> createHashFunction(int sz) {
    int mvLeft = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(30);
    int mvRight = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(16);
    int mvLeft2 = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(10);
    int mvRight2 = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(16);
    int mvLeft3 = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(16);
    int mvRight3 = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(20);
    return (key) -> {
        // These operations are totally random, and has no mathematical background beneath them!
        key = ~key + (key << mvLeft);
        key = key ^ (key >>> mvRight);
        key = key + (key << mvLeft2);
        key = key ^ (key >>> mvRight2);
        key = key + (key << mvLeft3);
        key = key ^ (key >>> mvRight3);
        return (int) (Math.abs(key) % sz); // sz is the size of target array
    };
}
```

For each test array find such a combination of parameters, that max bucket size is the smallest.

Some testing (input array has the size of 10k, filled with random elements):

- Hash mapping into [0..262k] results in a bucket of 2 items max. 5k random arrays tested, single-threaded version finds hash functions at ~100 arrays/second rate.

Considering that with the max bucket size of 2 it is possible to map both values into one 64-bit integer, this approach will result in only one memory jump and the simplest operations for CPU - hashing is made through xor, plus and shifts, which should be extremely fast as well as bits comparison.

However your data may not be so good, and may require bucket size of 3, which destroys possibility of `long long` usage for bucket items. In this case you can try to find some decent hash function instead of the random mess I've written.

Comment: This is similar to perfect hashing as suggested by @JonChesterfield,best suggestion yet.

Comment: @user2413068, my main idea was to show that you can eliminate potentially slow operations, which are inevitable when using usual approaches - e.g. Trie or generic hash maps (which has no limitation on bucket size). Also my thoughts on bucket of size 2-3 look wrong for me now - you'll have to specify the size of the bucket anyway. In fact all you need to do is to find max bucket size `L` and place each bucket's data in the next fashion: `[L,val1,val2,...,valL]`, this will result in `((L+1)*4)*sz` bytes of memory per each array.

Comment: @user2413068, just wanted to emphasize - the main issue when designing such systems is that people tend to measure performance in asymptotic complexity, while main consideration should be the amount of CPU ticks and heap memory jumps. I've met situations when `O(n*lg^2(n))` outperformed `O(n)` algorithm at `n ~ 1kk`, because of ineffective operations in the second one.

Comment: yeah that make sense, of course in the end it's profiling that will determine the best solution and not complexity. Thanks for your insight.

Comment: You could also consider [gperf](https://www.gnu.org/software/gperf/) which is an existing software package to search for perfect hashes. The hash functions it comes up with are of a different form to the above, usually involving lookups in small arrays to build the hash function, but depending on the surrounding code it may or may not be faster than an add/xor/shift-style hash. It usually finds hash functions with _zero_ collisions, which makes the lookup quite simple.